# Easy way to change apache www location

Tags: apache2, www

Instead of changing permissions to `/var/www`, installing nautilus permission related extensions or having to execute gksu i want to know an easy to do way of changing `/var/www` to another place like `/home/cyrex/www` for example. This way I save on doing all the permission related problems.

Comment: I was looking for this to connect my Dropbox directory to my /www since I have this setup on my work Mac and home Mac and my Windows VM, now with this I can set it up on my Ubuntu box and have a "local" server thats connected to 4 computers!

Comment: FYI, I used GUIs for Mac and Windows (MAMP Pro and WAMP)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well i could close the question but just found the answer here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP (The community help has gotten better)

Anyway the faster way was to edit the file of apache from **`/etc/apache2/sites-available/`** in my case it was **`000-default`**. Change all the **`/var/www`** entries (in my case 2) to the directory you want `www` to be in. This is the way without the virtual Hosts which is also mention in that link.