# install codeigniter on apache

Tags: installation, apache2

I already have php and apache installed on my ubuntu  12.04. I want to install codeigniter which is a php framework. I followed the link: [How to install CodeIgniter?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25446/how-to-install-codeigniter) . But its too complicated and also I do not want to create symlinks and mount and all the stuff mentioned there.
Installation instruction are also on the codegniter site i.e. http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/installation/index.html , but those are not elaborative and little confusing.

I will be very thankful if anyone can please provide a simple way to install codeigniter with apache server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to install Apache and have some form of a PHP interpreter setup to use CodeIgniter.

The simplest way is to install Apache with mod_php and ensure that mod_php is loaded within Apache. Another way is to setup Apache with FastCGI and use php-fpm.

You should be able to get setup with `# apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5 apache2`