# Managing a remote ubuntu server

Tags: partitioning, ftp

I hire an Ubuntu server which I access remotely and I purchased a domain for my webpage. I am totally new to this server thing and to Ubuntu as well. What applications should I install on the server?

- I need to transfer files to the server, I guess I would use FileZilla
  the same way I use it to upload files to my free website. But to have
  a username and password should I install an ftp server and create a
  user on Ubuntu?
- My website will send automated messages to users, so do I need to
  install a mail server as well?
- What other software should I install on the server apart from a
  firewall and an anti-virus?
- Should I partition the hard drive (3TB) and how? How partitions
  should I create and in what size for what applications?

Btw I use Windows 7 on my computer, so I am basically a windows user.

Comment: What automated messages do you want to send to users?

Comment: This is too many questions mangled into one, this system works best when questions are posted one at a time, please split these up, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To have authorized ftp access, first you need to install ftp server like `vsftpd`. For authorized access to the ftp, config `/etc/vsftpd.conf` and set the following variables:

```
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
```

Now you can log in by users and get access to it's HOME folder.

To specify the home folder of for example `ftp` user first make new directory; and then assign folder to the ftp user:

```
sudo mkdir /srv/ftp
sudo usermod -d /srv/ftp ftp
```

Full description about ftp-server on Ubuntu [is available here](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/ftp-server.html).

edit:
**How to specify the ftp folder to http server**
It is assumed that server has the LAMP-server already installed. To specify the ftp folder to the Apache you should change the configurations of Apache [as described here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20106/easy-way-to-change-apache-www-location).